# Create a .bib file from bibitem (thebibliography)

Tags: latex, bibtex

I have like 200 bibitem entry in the environment

```
\begin{thebibliography}
\bibitem{Bermudez} Berm\'udez, J.D., J. V. Segura y E. Vercher (2010). \emph{Bayesian forecasting with the Holt-Winters model}. Journal of the Operational Research Society, 61, 164-171.
\begin{thebibliography}
```

I want the resulting .bib file format

```
@article{bermudez2010bayesian,
  title={Bayesian forecasting with the Holt--Winters model},
  author={Berm{\'u}dez, Jos{\'e} D and Segura, Jos{\'e} Vicente and Vercher, Enriqueta},
  journal={Journal of the Operational Research Society},
  volume={61},
  number={1},
  pages={164--171},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

Is there a way I can do it without converting one by one

Regards

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use https://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca/ to convert the `\bibitem` into bibtex format. Choosing Spanish as language, the output of the conversion is

```
@article{Bermudez,
author = {Berm\'udez, J. D. and J. V. Segura and E. Vercher},
journal = {Journal of the Operational Research Society},
pages = {164-171},
title = {{B}ayesian forecasting with the Holt-Winters model},
volume = {61},
year = {2010},
}
```

Some fields are missing, e.g. the publisher, because this information was not contained in your `\bibitem`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tex2bib](https://github.com/juusechec/tex2bib#readme), a tool based on [text2bib](https://text2bib.economics.utoronto.ca), but migrated to a newest PHP version (PHP 7).

See an example of use

Input of text transformation:

```
\bibitem{Bermudez} Berm\'udez, J.D., J. V. Segura y E. Vercher (2010). \emph{Bayesian forecasting with the Holt-Winters model}. Journal of the Operational Research Society, 61, 164-171.
```

Output:

```
@article{bv10,
author = {Berm\'udez, J. D. and J. V. Segura y E. Vercher},
title = {Bayesian forecasting with the Holt-Winters model},
journal = {Journal of the Operational Research Society},
year = {2010},
volume = {61},
pages = {164-171},
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30389105)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the `y` not being recognised as `and`